# Difference between foldLeft and foldRight in cats

Tags: scala, fold, scala-cats

In the cats documentation we're reading:

> Foldable[F] is implemented in terms of two basic methods:
>
> - `foldLeft(fa, b)(f)` eagerly performs a left-associative fold over fa.
> - `foldRight(fa, b)(f)` lazily performs a right-associative fold over fa.

Is there a reason for this "lack of symmetry"?

Comment: WDYM? About the lazy vs eager. The thing is that not all types have a stack safe `foldRight` but all do have a stack safe `foldLeft`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez that's exactly what I mean, could you elaborate in an answer, please?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I think I understand though, it's like with the list - it's recursive and `foldRight` is not stack-safe. But how do I know that every such recursive data structure has a stack-safe `foldLeft`? (Sorry if it's lack of cs education from my side)

Comment: Ok so this a very simple explanation and lack a lot of foundations and references, which I hope someone can fill in a proper answer. - AFAIK, for all known types that you can implement `foldLeft` and `foldRight` they can be divided into two groups finite and infinite. For finite data structures we only care about stack safety and for all that I know their `foldLeft` is always stack safe whereas I know some whose `foldRight` isn't _(not sure if there is a formal proof for the `foldLeft`)_.

Comment: Now, for infinite types, we care about non-terminating computations, due associativity `foldLeft` will always be non-terminating on an infinite collection. However, `foldRight` can terminate if the operation is also lazy. And, since `Eval` can also ensure stack safety, the **cats**' maintainers decided to make their `foldRight`  to depend on `Eval`. - Again, all these are things I know from a practical perspective, but probably there are formal proofs.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you, that sounds reasonable and gave me a good intuition, maybe a reference to some formalisms will appear! Once again you've helped me a lot!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez can you post your comment as an answer?